# can't access php DateTime contents

Tags: php, datetime

I've got a variable that upon `var_dump` prints this.

It contains a date, but I just don't know how to access the date data, if I put

`$myVariable[date]` OR `$myVariable["date"]` OR `$myVariable['date']` all result in error.

```
object(DateTime)#8 (3) { 
    ["date"]=> string(19) "2011-07-25 00:00:00"
    ["timezone_type"]=> int(3)
    ["timezone"]=> string(16) "Europe/Stockholm"
}
```

I don't understand what the first number is either, the `#8` right after the `(DateTime)`...

Comment: What exactly do you want to access? Check the php DateTime reference:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $myVariable->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

([thanks to kmfk for that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255941/nested-objects-mixed-results-from-dql-select))