# Nested Objects (mixed results from DQL select)

Tags: php, object, doctrine-orm

I have a doctrine2 query like this:

```
$query = $this -> doctrine -> em -> createQuery ("SELECT a, b FROM ORM\Dynasties2\Maillinks a JOIN a.msgId b");
```

It returns [mixed results](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results), similar to this:

```
ORM\Dynasties2\Maillinks Object 
( 
    [id:ORM\Dynasties2\Millinks:private] => 1 
    [toUser:ORM\Dynasties2\Maillinks:private] => 16 
    [isRead:ORM\Dynasties2\Maillinks:private] => 0 
    [msgId:ORM\Dynasties2\Maillinks:private] => ORM\Dynasties2\Mailmsgs Object 
    ( 
        [id:ORM\Dynasties2\Mailmsgs:private] => 1 
        [msgText:ORM\Dynasties2\Mailmsgs:private] => asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf 
        [fromUser:ORM\Dynasties2\Mailmsgs:private] => 13 
        [timeStamp:ORM\Dynasties2\Mailmsgs:private] => DateTime Object 
        (       
            [date] => 2012-04-20 12:17:29 
            [timezone_type] => 3 
            [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles 
        ) 
        [onTurn:ORM\Dynasties2\Mailmsgs:private] => 1 
        [importance:ORM\Dynasties2\Mailmsgs:private] => 2 
        [msgType:ORM\Dynasties2\Mailmsgs:private] => 1 
    ) 
)
```

I can access some of the data, at the 'top' easily enough.
`echo $row -> getToUser();` returns '16'

I tried `echo $row -> msgId-> getMsgText();` but that returns `Fatal error: Cannot access private property ORM\Dynasties2\Maillinks::$msgId`

**How do I access the data in the objects within?**

Or:  is my query and result broken?  Do I need to do something different with my query or entities?

Comment: as a quick side note - if you have control of the entities, I would recommend changing your getter from `getMsgId()` to `getMsg()` - it would help make that more clear, as that method is not returning an id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this not work for you?

```
$row->getMsgId()->getMsgText();
```

You should be able to check the actual entities files ( whether you had doctrine build them, or someone else did ) to check the getters and setters for that entity.

Comment: How can I access the [date] data in the timeStamp object?   echo $row-> getMsgId() -> getTimeStamp() -> date();  did not seem to do it, nor did getDate().   Its not one that I set up an entity for.

Comment: `echo $row->getMsgId()->getTimeStamp()->date;`
Edited this, its a DateTime object, not an array, my last suggestion wouldnt have worked

Comment: Message: Undefined property: DateTime::$date     doing get_object_vars on timeStamp gives: array(3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-04-20 12:17:29" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(19) "America/Los_Angeles" } asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf

Comment: sorry - should have known better. use `format()`, takes a string format like `date()` would.  `echo $row->getMsgId()->getTimeStamp()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`